# Python BS4 unwrap() scraped xml data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a journalist working on a project using web scrapping to pull data from the county jail site. I'm still teaching myself python and am trying to get a list of charges and the bail that was assigned for that charge. The site uses xml, and I've been able to pull the data for charges and bail and write it to a csv file but I'm having trouble using the unwrap() function to remove tags. I've tried it out in a few places and can't seem to figure out its usage. I'd really like to do this in the code and not just have to run a find and replace in the spreadsheet.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime

url="https://legacyweb.randolphcountync.gov/sheriff/jailroster.xml"
xml = requests.get(url)
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
   print("Connecting to jail website:")
   print("Connected - Response code:", response)
   print("Scraping Started at ", datetime.now())

   soup = BeautifulSoup(xml.content, 'lxml')

   charges = soup.find_all('ol')
   bail_amt = soup.find_all('ob')

with open('charges-bail.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    chargesbail = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    chargesbail.writerow([charges.unwrap(), bail_amt.unwrap()])
```

CSV File

```
"[<ol>BREAKING AND OR ENTERING (F)</ol>, <ol>POSS STOLEN GOODS/PROP (F)</ol>, <...
```

Comment: I guess the site doesn't work outside the US or it's just broken.

Comment: @baduker The url just goes to the xml file. In chrome I had to add "view-source:" to the url to see the data, otherwise it loads a blank page. I don't know if they have any visitor restrictions setup on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the `unwrap()` function, you just need to access the text within an element. I suggest you search on `<of>` which is above both the `<ol>` and `<ob>` entries. Doing this will avoid your lists of ol and ob entries getting out of sync as not all entries have an `ob`.

Try the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://legacyweb.randolphcountync.gov/sheriff/jailroster.xml"
print("Connecting to jail website:")
req_xml = requests.get(url)
print("Connected - Response code:", req_xml)

if req_xml.status_code == 200:
    with open('charges-bail.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        chargesbail = csv.writer(csvfile)
        
        print("Scraping Started at ", datetime.now())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req_xml.content, 'lxml')

        for of in soup.find_all('of'):
            if of.ob:
                ob = of.ob.text
            else:
                ob = ''
                
            chargesbail.writerow([of.ol.text, ob])
```

Which would give you an output CSV file starting:

```
BREAKING AND OR ENTERING (F),
LARCENY AFTER BREAK/ENTER,
POSS STOLEN GOODS/PROP (F),5000
HABEAS CORPUS,100000
ELECTRONIC HOUSE ARREST VIOLAT,25000
```

The code `of.ob.text` is shorthand for: from the `of` find the first `ob` entry and then return the text contained inside or:

```py
of.find('ob').get_text()
```

To only write rows when both are present, you could change it to:

```py
for of in soup.find_all('of'):
    if of.ob and of.ob.get_text(strip=True):
        chargesbail.writerow([of.ol.text, of.ob.get_text(strip=True)])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! If I only want it to write to the csv file when there is text in both ol and ob would I be able to do that in the else/if loop?

Comment: You're welcome! I have updated the answer to show how to only write a row when both are present

Comment: I used the code you added to the answer and its still writing rows with empty `ob`. Is it possible that its picking up that the `ob` tag is present within the `of` element? (If so, could adding something like `if of.ob is not ''` to the statement work?

Comment: It probably means there is an `ob` tag but it is empty. Just add an extra test for non-empty

Comment: Sorry, I'm still activly trying to learn python. The `ob` tag is included in all `of` elements but is only filled in when there is a bail amount. I did try adding `if of.ob.text is not '':` to the end of the `if` statement and it wrote 3 charges with their bail amount to the csv file then errored out with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: I have updated the code needed. It first checks if `of.ob` is present and then checks if there is any text (spaces are removed in case there is any entry with just spaces). If you don't test first, `of.ob` can be `None`. So doing `None.text` would give you that error message.

Comment: First, you are amazing that worked perfect! Secondly, I think I understand. Its checking to see if there is text in both `of` and `ob`, if there is it uses strip to remove any spaces to prevent any `ob` fields that are empty, then writes them to the csv file. That is awesome. I like python so much more than the VB I had to learn in school. Thank you again.

Comment: I would recommend you add print statements so you can see what each thing is doing, e.g. `print(of)`